# Change values of a particular column to value_count()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose i have the following data set. I need to replace the value of a particular column by the value_count(). I saw few posts where it is done for the entire data set. I need to do it for a particular column.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Item 1': ['apple', 'potato', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'potato', 'egg'],
          'Item 2': [1,5,2,7,8,4,9,0,3],
          'Item 3': ['a','b','a','c','d','c','e','e','e']})
```

How do i replace the values of column 'Item 1' by the value_counts()?

I tried the following code.

```
data.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))
```

But this is applying to whole data. I need to do it for one column.

The resulting value should be of the form -

'Cheese':3

'Potato':2

Comment: Are you trying to change, for example, all `'cheese' ` entries to `3`? Please post code of what you have tried.

Comment: @Edmund I have edited the post. Yes, i am trying to change 'cheese' to 3,  'potato' to 2 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Do value_count outside of loop to avoid doing it multiple times
vc_item1 = data['Item 1'].value_counts()

data['Item 1'].apply(lambda x: vc_item1[x])
```

But if understand your comment correctly you want both key and value in each cell:

```
vc = data['Item 1'].value_counts()

data['Item 1'].apply(lambda x: str(x) + ':' + str(vc[(x)]))
```

Comment: above code works fine. I need to display data in the form cheese:3, potato:2 etc. Like key:value pair

Comment: Sounds like you just want the value count itself. Maybe my edit will help.

Comment: I don't need data in dict form. The value stored in each row should be of key:value pair

Comment: Hmm, are you saying you want both key and value inside each cell? Should they be together as a string? It is hard to tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes key:value inside each cell. For example, cheese:3. Cell has key cheese, and value is the frequency of cheese(3).